# How do I sort a string-combination (title, phrases) in the last column (after tab) using regEx?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am currently working on a python program in a batchmode which prints out the string-combinations (e.g names news titles) sorted according to its most frequent hit. 
Now, the string to be matched is in the last column (after a tab). I'm working with the results of another task (so I'll be using `sys.argv[1]`).
The document to be searched has this format:

> 2 Hugh MacDonald (archer) Hugh Macdonald
>   2 Wikipedia_talk:Requests_for_adminship/Paulmcdonald    talk
>   2 Kennedy Macdonald Thomas Kennedy Macdonald
>   1 </nowiki>[[Wikipedia:WikiProject_Spam/Local/donaldsonwilliams.com]]<nowiki>

etc.

Basically what I need here is the string after tab. 
so far my code looks like this but does not work (full-linkStats.txt contains the strings): (thanks a lot in advance :))

```js
import re
import sys

def read_file(filename):
    try:
        file = open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
        text = file.readlines()
        file.close()
        return text
    except IOError:
        print('cannot open file: ', filename)

text = open('full-linkStats.txt', 'r')
#word = re.search('^\t[(\w+)\s\d]+', text)
#f = open('test_solution.txt', 'w')
#f.write(re.search('^\t[(\w+)\s\d]+', text))
#f.close()
#text.close()


def main():
    f = read_file('full-linkStats.txt')
    for lines in f:
        match = re.search(r'\t(w+)+', lines)
        if match:
            a = match.group()
            print(a)
            open("test_solution.txt", "w").write(a)
            return a
print(main())
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

To find the text after the last tab for each line in the sample:

```
for line in my_sample_text:
    match = re.search(r'\t([^\t]+)$', line)
    if match:
        after_last_tab = match.groups()[0]
        print(after_last_tab)
```

This works because of the regex:

> r'\t([^\t]+)$'

which says, find a tab (`\t`), then group one or more not tabs (`[^\t]+`) until the end of line (`$`)

I used this sample:

```
my_sample_text = """
2\tHugh MacDonald (archer) Hugh Macdonald
2\tWikipedia_talk:Requests_for_adminship/Paulmcdonald talk
2\tKennedy Macdonald Thomas Kennedy Macdonald
1\t</nowiki>[[Wikipedia:WikiProject_Spam/Local/donaldsonwilliams.com]]<nowiki>
""".split('\n')[1:-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot! 
I solved finally came to solution by solving it like this:(it found all matches)

```js
pattern = re.compile('\t[A-Za-z0-9 .,\-\(\)\'\')&;]+') 
    with codecs.open(filename, 'r', 'utf-8') as file:
            text = file.read()
            matches = []
            for m in re.findall(pattern, text):
                matches.append(m)
```